# how do i redirect the iframe directory to another html file if it does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

so i was working on my project called "HTML GIZMO" and i realised that switching between html pages makes your search history wayy too clutered so i made an iframe that displays the original project so only one item will be displayed in the search history.[with iframe and switched pages multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPI7.png) [without iframe and switched pages multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZb2g.png).

but whenever the iframe encounters a problem like this where the item is either moved, edited, or delted, [it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTLv.png). it doesnt really look good so i wanted for whenever this error shows up i want the iframe to change the link to another html file that says an error occured. so like i want it to show the html file that says error has occured to be inside the iframe if this happens. here is my iframe file code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/htmlicon.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HTML GIZMO</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="contentFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
        const targetPageUrl = './main/home.html';
        const iframe = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
        iframe.src = targetPageUrl;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i would really appreciate it if someone could help me!

Comment: The history with all the entries, would allow me to directly go to a specific piece of content again. Your version, which would only load the initial content into the iframe, would then likely require me to perform additional navigation clicks, to again get to the particular content that I am interested. IMHO you are not improving anything here, but you are actively _decreasing_ usability.

Comment: i wasnt aiming for usability, i was more focused on reducing the items in the search history.

Comment: But _why_, these entries being there is _part of_ the usability ... Why would you _deliberately_ try to create something, that works _worse_ for me, than the default behavior?

Comment: its a long story

Answer (score 0):

you can just add an error event listener like this:

```
iframe.addEventListener('error', function() {
    iframe.src = "error.html";
});
```

So if the item is either moved, edited, or deleted, you can just specify which page to redirect.

Comment: i don't know if it works for you, but it doesn't work for me it still says that same error